# Effect on power supply when running DC motor in nearly the stall torque

Tags: dc-motor

I have a DC motor connected to a 12V DC power supply from rectifier. Sometime the load increases than usual and motor RPM reduces. This in turn makes a voltage drop in the power supply something like 2-3 volt. I have a voltage meter connected to it for monitoring.
Is it okay to run the motor like this or will it have any negative impact on the power supply system. I am not worried about the overheating of the motor and reduced life time of it.

Comment: Show the circuit and include values and names of components.

Comment: It is a 12V DC power supply

Answer (score 3):

The power supply voltage dropping 2-3 volts when the motor load increases means that the power supply cannot deliver all the current that the motor would take. You should consider a power supply with a greater output capacity so that its output stays at 12V for the full range of loads that you expect to put on the motor.

Some power supplies may very well overheat and burnout if you continued to stress the output at more current than it is rated for. Other power supplies will have current limiting on their outputs to protect from the supply becoming overheated. You will have to consider the design attributes of your supply so you can safely use it with your motor application.

Comment: DC motor is 35W. Power Supply is 180W. There will not be any issue even if motor is consuming full of its capacity. When the motor is nearly stalled (this happens when using low power motor for bigger load), the back emf is reduced and it makes a drop in voltage in power supply. In this case, will there be a problem. Or in other words, is it okay to stall any DC motor when its life is not considered. will it have negative impact on power supply?

Comment: @James - Everything I said still applies. When you are stalling the motor it is clearly drawing way more current that the supply can provide if you truly are seeing a 2-3V drop at the output of the supply. A 12V 180W supply presumably is rated for 15A. Your stalled motor must be drawing that much or more. If instead you were seeing the voltage drop of 2-3 volts right at the motor and the 12V supply output is staying at 12V then the high current of the stalled motor is causing a voltage drop in the wiring that you used to hook up the motor.